# TypeError: browser is undefined (Web Extension Messaging)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to communicate my web page script with my content script of my web extension with the code below

**Web Page Script**

```
const browser = window.browser || window.chrome;
browser.runtime.sendMessage(message,
     function (response) {
          console.log(response);
     }
);
```

However, I keep getting the error `TypeError: browser is undefined`. The same goes if I use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` instead.

How am I supposed to use this method?

Comment: You can use the standard DOM messaging via CustomEvent between the page and the content script. Note, `chrome.runtime` is exposed only to HTTPS pages in new Chrome, see https://crbug.com/835287

Comment: But I want the extension to give back a response, based on the message sent. As events are not designed for returning a value, how could I do it?

Comment: But you can. See the documentation and examples for CustomEvent.

Comment: (Of course you'll have to send the response in a separate event)

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that user/webpage scripts (unprivileged scripts) don't have access to JavaScript API for security purposes and `browser`,  `chrome` are part of JavaScript APIs which can only be accessed by privileged scripts like web extension's background scripts and content scripts (again content scripts don't have access to all the JavaScript APIs). Basically, if you need to send data from web page script to background script, `CustomEvent` should be used to send data to a content script which acts as a bridge and from there send that data to background script using `browser.runtime.sendMessage`. PFB sample code

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("myEvent",{
        detail:["Hello","World"]
    }));
}
```

contentscript.js

```
document.addEventListener("myEvent", function (event) {
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: event.detail
});
```

background.js

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
     data = message.data;
     // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason for me to call background.js (e.g. performance) instead of performing the actions in contentscript.js?

Comment: Depends on the use case, as mentioned above content scripts do not have access to all of the JavaScript APIs. Please find more info [here] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts)