# Mozilla FF browser.tabs.create() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a problem with my own extension for mozilla firefox. I want to open a new tab after click event on a document. I wrote this:

```
  (() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('click');
      browser.tabs.create({});
    });
  })();
```

What is wrong with my code? Console prints'click' so event works. Also in manifest.json I have this permission (and only this one):

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
```

I will be very gratefull for an answear :)

Answer (score 5):

The "browser.tabs" API only works in a background script. You are using it in a content script. Most APIs in WebExtensions only work in a background script.

From MDN:

> JavaScript APIs for WebExtensions can be used inside the extension's
>   background scripts and in any other documents bundled with the
>   extension, including browser action or page action popups, sidebars,
>   options pages, or new tab pages. A few of these APIs can also be
>   accessed by an extension's content scripts (see the list in the
>   content script guide).

Please read more about WebExtensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API

The answer to this question contains more info: [TypeError: browser is undefined (Web Extension Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378133/typeerror-browser-is-undefined-web-extension-messaging)